# BackUp External HDD in local network NAS

Tags: networking, hard-drive, backup

I have an external HDD that I want to automatically back-up daily in a NAS. The NAS is available through a local network.

My best guess for backing-up the drive is creating an image through the disk utility and saving it in the NAS. Is it the correct procedure? Are there any ways to automate this action in a scheduled manner?

Thank you all!

Comment: Image backup is not the best. It consumes lots of space and has to copy entire partition(s) each time, but does include any deleted files that rsync may not include. If external & automated, you must be sure it is always connected or you will have issues. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync You can schedule in cron.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto Does this drive have an install or just data? Does some data not change as often. You often can use rsync for media and rdiff for data that changes a lot. http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/examples.html

Comment: Thank you @oldfred for your answer. It is exactly what I need since a lot of data do not change often. Unfortunately, I tried to reach the NAS using SSH but it always refuses the connection, I can only write in it using the Files UI. Anyway, when I will solve this problem rdiff is what I need.

Comment: Some more info: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2457329 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2440020 Is IP address fixed? Is this always a local network? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2419993